# Fix Two Elements Offset by Less Than One Pixel

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I want the two elements shown in this image to line up exactly, but the top and bottom are offset by less than one pixel (when I add a 1px margin to the top or bottom it shifts it by too much). Why are these not lined up perfectly?

[image]

```
<div id="entities-table-header-button-container">
    <%= link_to 'New Entity', new_entity_path, class: "btn btn-primary rounded-r-none border-r-2" %>

    <div id="entities-table-batch-actions-dropdown-toggle" class="-ml-1 z-10 inline-flex items-center align-middle leading-none rounded no-underline text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-800 lg:rounded-none">
      <div class="relative" data-controller="dropdown">
        <div id="entities-table-batch-actions-dropdown" data-action="click->dropdown#toggle click@window->dropdown#hide touch->dropdown#toggle touch@window->dropdown#hide" role="button" class="flex items-center">
          <div class="inline-block select-none">
            <span class="btn btn-primary appearance-none flex px-1 inline-block text-white rounded-l-none border-solid border-0 border-gray-600">
              <!-- Batch Actions -->
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="1rem" height="1rem" class="fill-current text-white lg:inline hidden h-5 w-5"><path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"></path></svg>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
```

The goal is for my buttons to look like this (but with my own styling, so less rounded, different colors, etc.):

[image]

Comment: You can try adding vertical-align:top; to that span which contains the svg.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Edit: Actually I just added "align-top" from Tailwind, which worked.